# Search index in array for a given value

Tags: php, arrays

How do I get the index of an array for a given positive value or 1 below is my array.

```
Array( [0] => stdClass Object
    ( [result] => )

[1] => stdClass Object
    ( [result] => 1 )

[2] => stdClass Object
    ( [result] => )

[3] => stdClass Object
    ( [result] => )

[4] => stdClass Object
    ( [result] => )

[5] => stdClass Object
    ( [result] => )

[6] => stdClass Object
    ( [result] => 1 )
 )
```

The above array result was come from this function, what it does, was to verify email address submitted to PQ and if the email is valid and registered it will return 1 or true, now i need to isolate this valid and registered email, as I need to send invitation to the rest of emails.

```
  function get_email_verification(){
         $api_request_url = "http://api.payquicker.com/api/IsActiveAccount";
        foreach ($this->get_payquicker_emails() as $email) {
                $param = "email=".$email;
                $result_request[] =  $this->do_request($api_request_url, $param, 'GET', 'json');

        }
        if (empty($result_request)) {
            echo "All payee emails are already registered to Payquicker";
        }
       return $result_request; 
      }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. What is the desired output for that array?

Comment: @ George Brighton I need to find the index of the array which has value greater than zero.

Comment: In other words 1 and 6 would be returned by this search algorithm?

Comment: @Chris Rasco Exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

DEMO HERE: http://codepad.org/Hk5ufuG8

```
$data = Array();
$data[0] = (object)Array("result" => '');
$data[1] = (object)Array("result" => 1);
$data[2] = (object)Array("result" => '');
$data[3] = (object)Array("result" => '');
$data[4] = (object)Array("result" => '');
$data[5] = (object)Array("result" => '');
$data[6] = (object)Array("result" => 1);

function searchArray($array)
{
    $our_keys = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $obj)
    {
        if($obj->result > 0)
        {
            $our_keys[] = $key;

        }
    }
    return $our_keys;
}

$keys = searchArray($data);
print_r($keys);
```

UPDATE - Try this for your get_email_verification() function. It stores the emails into an array called $emails, processes them as before, but instead of returning the above array we go ahead and call the searchArray() right then and process the results against the $emails array and return that list.

```
function get_email_verification()
{
    $api_request_url = "http://api.payquicker.com/api/IsActiveAccount";
    $emails = $this->get_payquicker_emails();
    foreach ($emails as $email)
    {
        $param = "email=".$email;
        $result_request[] =  $this->do_request($api_request_url, $param, 'GET', 'json');
    }
    if (empty($result_request))
    {
        echo "All payee emails are already registered to Payquicker";
    }

    $email_keys = searchArray($result_request);
    $results = Array();
    foreach($email_keys as $key)
    {
        $results[] = $emails[$key];
    }

    return $results; 
}
```

Comment: do i need first to convert my return array ?

Comment: The function returns an array of keys that should match up with the corresponding email addresses that were sent to PQ. You may need to store the email addresses in an array you can reference before sending them to PQ

Comment: yap $param = "email=".$email; the $email is an array of emails after sending them to PQ, the APIs returns only boolean value. my problem is to reference that email. My idea was to search first that index after getting that index search again that index in email arrays. But if there is any solution better than mine, it would be a big help and really appreciate it.

Comment: @shadeniniski I updated my answer with another possible update. Give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your example array shows multiple items with a result value of > 1, so I assume you want to extract the index of all of these items?

You could loop through the array, check if each item has a result > 0, if it does add it's index to a new array.

```
$results = array();

foreach($your_array as $key=>$item) {
   if($item['result'] > 0){
      $results[] = $key;
   }
}
```

The result for your example array would be an array with values `[1,6]`

Comment: Yes, sorry I was going on you saying array, while your code shows it is an object. You should use `$item->result` to access the information.